# How to uninstall manually installed java? (jdk 8)

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, jdk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit and installed the wrong version of Sun/Oracle's Java JDK (32 bit instead of 64 bit) using the [Ask Ubuntu Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre?newreg=15b83875d47d434a8bad86f71d62b5b8)

I assume I have to uninstall it now. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javac
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javaws
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
```

Comment: @Testing360 No problem :)

Comment: That last command is wrong. It will remove anything below ./jvm/. That could be just jdk1.8.0 but a lot more.

Comment: @Rinzwind What could that be, aside from other installations of java, which have been excluded?

Comment: @Rinzwind Plus notice that i specified "Assuming you have followed the tutorial exactly as described in the link", which implies the creation of such folder.

Comment: @kos it could also have other versions of Java in /usr/lib/jvm/ and those would be removed as well. Your rm is missing `jdk1.8.0/`. You should expect users to just copy and paste the commands you provide.

Comment: @Rinzwind Have you read the post? It states: "Assuming that you have only that installation of java", so it's logical that if that's not the case one shouldn't use those commands.

Comment: @jos again: please assume users will just copy and paste commands. You are setting them up for a failure.

Comment: @Rinzwind Ok, i changed my answer accordingly